# How to move a triangulation in matlab

Tags: matlab, triangulation

I have made a 3D delaunay triangulation in matlab with some defined points. Considering it a consistent triangulation (I mean with fixed edges and angles) I want to move this triangulatoin in the space and then compute the location of one point by giving other points' location.
I have searched a lot on the net but I couldn't find a proper solution for this problem. Actually there isn't any similar example.

Comment: How exactly did you store your data(points,edges etc)?

Comment: My data is stored in its XYZ format. Consider a set of n points which is represented by a n*3 vector. Actually after defining the triangulation in matlab, I have the matrix of edges also.

Comment: Ok, and what do you mean by 'compute the location of one point by giving other points' location'?

Comment: Consider a triangulation which is defined by a set of n points with their xyz data. Then we move this triangulation in the 3d space. So the position of all of the points will be changed. Now consider that we know the second position of n-1 points and only the second position of one point is unknown. I want to calculate this position using other point's position and other data from the triangulation.

Comment: Ok, if I got the problem right maybe this approach might work: Using your adjacency matrix it is possible to obtain the set of neighbour points (lets call the set N) which have edges connecting to the point of later unknown position (lets call this point P). Now obtain the relative position of P to each member of N. This information applied to the new positions of N should give you the new position of P.